SNNs with low-moderate data requirements?
I've been looking into utilizing a survival neural network for my dataset, but am having difficulty finding a model that works with my relatively low amount of data. I have ~10 datapoints for ~300 individuals with 8 inputs, and would like to train my model to predict mortality risk. I've tried using a standard NN with data at each timepoint being the input and the corresponding "time until death" being the output and have had decent results, but it feels somewhat wasteful. I've tried using models online such as tdCoxSNN but am getting poor outputs. Any algorithms you guys are familiar with? My reason for using a NN is that I'm applying it to a different dataset without death values
